# Wordpress authentication issue

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am having problem with an htaccess authentification.

I have a wordpress website and would like to restrict access on it. In the root folder, i have added an htaccess and a htpasswd.

Htaccess codes:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /home/anglolabs/webapps/financial/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

And the htpasswd is as such:

```
admin:$apr1$wcax9ykl$uH5ktq9NL/9fqtw5lzYLy1
```

I am being prompted the box but when entering the username/password, I am being redirected to "500-Internal Server Error".

Comment: You might try putting the Auth rules before Wordpress rules for a start.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the HTTP Auth is working, but you Apache/PHP is busted.

500 means there was an error executing the PHP. Check your server logs, if you have questions post back what the logs show (might need to use Github Gist or Pastbin)

Comment: Is there a way round this since I do not have access to the server logs.

Comment: Not really, there are so many things that can cause it, you'd be trying stuff and not knowing if you are causing further problems or not. You can try by setting things up locally on your machine and see if they run. But it could be anything from your .htaccess files, to apache configuration, to file permissions on the server

Comment: Thanks Ryan Gibbons. I tried it locally and indeed encountered the same error.  Could you provide me a solution.

Comment: Take a look at your local logs, they should provide some information as to what is causing the issue.